# Odd SQL behavior, I'm wondering why this works the way it does

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Consider the following Transact sql.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(val VARCHAR(255) NULL)

INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('a')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('b')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('c')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('d')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES(NULL)

select val 
from @table
where val not in ('a')
```

I would expect this to return

```
b, c, d, NULL
```

but instead it returns

```
b, c, d
```

Why is this the case?  Is NULL not evaluated? Is NULL somehow in the set 'a'?

Comment: I believe if you alter your Where-Clause, you can still select those NULLs. Like so : `WHERE val NOT IN ('a') OR val IS NULL` . But, NULL is definitely not being set to 'a'.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem recently.  It's amazing how long you can use SQL before being burned by this behavior.

Comment: PS. I say on a regular basis 'I ******* hate Nulls!'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Answer**

By default, NULL, to SQL, means "unknown". So, any comparison to "unknown" is "unknown".

For example, if a stranger is standing next to Bob, and you want to ask the question, "Is the stranger's name the same as Bob's?". The answer is unknown.

Since you're asking, "Return any records where the value is not 'A'". When it gets to that NULL column, SQL still says, "I don't know". Since the expression doesn't evaluate to true, that record isn't returned.

**The Solution**

Any expression that compares NULL to a constant will always be NULL, so use the special `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to test for NULL values.

This will get you `b`, `c`, `d`, and `NULL`:

```
SELECT val 
FROM @table
WHERE val NOT IN ('a') OR val IS NULL
```

**The Workaround**

You can change the default behavior for NULLs:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

Comment: Thank you for the stranger comment.  I always looked at null as unset.  So if I asked is that strangers name the same as Bob's the answer would be no, because the stranger has no name.  Which is obviously not the same as expressed by set theory.

Comment: One caveat about the workaround: if you depend on this behavior, and your code is run "in the wild" (where you don't control the ANSI_NULLS setting), you may have seemingly random errors. Better *in that case* to test explicitly.

Comment: @DaveE, I agree. I don't recommend the workaround. The solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

to get the null row try:

```
select val 
from @table
where val not in ('a') OR val IS NULL
```

try these:

```
select 1 where null in (null)
select 1 where null in (1)
select 1 where 1 in (null)
```

all return zero rows

**null=null is always false** and **null=anythng is always false**, when testing the NULL row the WHERE clause is WHERE NULL in ('a'), so it is always false.

Comment: I understand that, but I am wondering why I have to state that, NULL is not in the set 'a' so I would expect that row to return.

Comment: Null is undefined, it cannot be determined whether or not it is in a set because it cannot be compared to anything.  Unless you change the way SQL Server handles nulls as suggested by Quesi.  Otherwise you must check whether a value is undefined (i.e. is null).

Comment: Matthew, NULL *never compares to anything*, not even itself. Because of that, you have to explicitly test for it using [NOT] IS NULL.  Null isn't included because it can not be tested for inclusion "in ('a')".

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am understanding how it works, but so many languages treat null as 'not a value' instead of 'unknown value' that the behavior surprises me.

Answer (score 2):

Null can't be directly compared to anything.

try

```
select val  
from @table 
where coalesce(val, '') not in ('a')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and you will get a different answer:

```
set ansi_nulls off;
DECLARE @table TABLE(val VARCHAR(255) NULL)

INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('a')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('b')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('c')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES('d')
INSERT INTO @table (val) VALUES(NULL)

select val 
from @table
where val not in ('a')
```

You have ansi_nulls on and so it treats nulls accordingly.

Comment: For more information google "mathematical set operations" and start reading up on set logic. Set logic is good background knowledge for working with an RDMS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do equality with NULL in this way.

Consider this

```
select case when 'a' = NULL then 1 else 0 end
select case when 'a' <> NULL then 1 else 0 end
```

For above you'll get

```
result
------
  0
  0
```

For your query try

```
 where isnull(val,'') not in ('a')
```